# Is there a way to directly save DNG Sequences to 16bit exr Sequences in Photoshop or After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, magic-lantern, raw

I want to prepare my Magic Lantern Raw files for Nuke. I use Photoshop to convert DNG to a 16bit tiff and then re-encode them to a 16bit exr sequence. I wish I could directly save as exr.
I know i could use Davinci Resolve I just don't like the workflow with Davinci...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using After Effects this is not an issue. After Effects has CameraRAW support and by that also support importing DNG sequences.
You import them just as you would any other image sequence.

Then simply make the sequence into a composition and add it to the render queue.
AFAIK After Effects has the OpenEXR plugin integrated since CS5.5. In case I'm wrong you can get the great ProEXR plugin for Photoshop and After Effects from [fnodware](http://www.fnordware.com/ProEXR/) (I'm not affiliated). To do the same with a few more format options.

[image: render exr sequence in AE]
[image: exr settings]

Comment: After Effects and Photoshop can open exr but as far as I can see not render as exr. Did not find the option in the Adobe Media encoder either... Fnodware seems to be for CS3 but maybe it works for Adobe CC too.

Comment: Sorry I was blind found the option in After Effects. It looks like they integrated the plugin from fnodware into after effects. Now wondering if i can find it in Photoshop too.

Comment: Photoshop also has OpenEXR but only when your image is 32bit. Otherwise it doesn't show up as a save option for whatever reason.
Maybe try the Photoshop Trial of ProExr, should allow you to save as 16bit aswell.